# How to compare Accountids in trigger

Tags: trigger

in my project I have one situation where I need to compare new `Accountids` with existing `Accountids` and needs to through an error if the id doesn't exist.

Help me with code.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is this standard salesforce ID you are talking about, then it will be always uniquely assigned by the system.

Comment: Yes I agree, but in my project as the data is coming from third party where they are sending data from their end with Salesforce ID(Account). Sometimes they are sending invalid id's(which are not existed in our database for Accounts), hence I need to cross check new incoming ID with existing ID and want to through an error.

Comment: Even if they send a salesforce ID to you, I don't think you can make it your Account record's ID, it will always be auto assigned by salesforce. But if you are talking about storing the ID in a new field, then it is fine.

Comment: We don't write code here.  Please share what you've tried so far, and many of us can help.  Or if you need direction to Apex documentation, start at Developer.salesforce.com

Comment: In this case, are you just intrested in validating if:
1. The ID is a possibly valid salesforce ID
OR 2. The salesforce ID is valid and already exists in the system as the ID of another existing account.

Comment: Stygon it's the part of integration, if they send data with existing Account ID then related account's data will be automatically updated. Yes salesforce auto assign Account IDs by using those IDs only they are sending data, but sometimes due to some internal issues they are sending wrong Account IDs, hence I need to cross check Account IDs.

Comment: Yes salesforce ID is valid and already exists in the system as the ID of another existing account, but the problem is in some thousands of account records some times they are sending invalid account ids and we are getting issues due to that one.

Comment: So they are trying to update existing records, hope my understanding is right

Comment: Yup Stygon that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the method. I hope this is what you are looking for

```
public static Set<ID> filterOutNonExistingIDs(Set<ID> InputAccIDs){ 
Set<ID> ExistingAccountIDSet = new Set<ID>();
for(Account Acc : [SELECT id FROM Account WHERE id IN :InputAccIDs]){
    ExistingAccountIDSet.add(Acc.id);
}
Set<ID> NonExistingAccountIDSet = new Set<ID>();
for(ID AccountID : InputAccIDs){
    if(!ExistingAccountIDSet.contains(AccountID)){
        NonExistingAccountIDSet.add(AccountID);
    }
}
return NonExistingAccountIDSet;
}
```

This method takes in a set of all IDs you need to validate. It returns you a set of IDs that dosent exist in the system. Hope this helps.

Comment: Now you can find out the IDs that dosent exist and throw an error if the returned Set is not empty.